# cliente webservice java

Tags: java, webservice, netbeans, lista, print

tengo un webservice que hace una consulta a un jdo y me devuelve un list como resultado (return)
el caso es que mi cliente puedo hacer la llamada, metiendo el restultado en una nueva lista y recorriendola para imprimirla de tal forma:

```
List<Pais> paisesmoneda = conexion.getPaisesMoneda("ALL");
Iterator iter2 = paisesmoneda.iterator();
while (iter2.hasNext()){
  System.out.println(iter2.next());
}
  }
```

pero al imprimir en pantalla me imprime de tal forma:
servidorwebservices.Pais@43556938
servidorwebservices.Pais@43556546...

como puedo hacer que en vez de darme la información esa me escriba los resultados reales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que te muestra es una representación de cadena del objeto. para poder imprimir los valores del objeto, debes crear el método toString al objeto Pais, el método toString devuelve una cadena que "representa textualmente" este objeto. El resultado debe ser una representación concisa pero informativa que sea fácil de leer para una persona. Se recomienda que todas las subclases anulen este método.

Comment: entiendo lo que dices pero no como puedo aplicarlo

Comment: te deje un ejemplo saludos.

Answer (score 0):

te dejo un ejemplo.

cree mi objeto Pais con 2 atributos

```
package patofer;

public class Pais {

    private Integer codPais;
    private String nombre;
    
    public Pais(Integer codPais, String nombre) {
        this.codPais = codPais;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    public Integer getCodPais() {
        return codPais;
    }
    public void setCodPais(Integer codPais) {
        this.codPais = codPais;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pais [codPais=" + codPais + ", nombre=" + nombre + "]";
    }    
}
```

al final cree mi clase toString, casi todos los ides te dan la opcion de crearla en forma automatica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esta parte del codigo cree una clase main donde asigno valores a la clase pais y luego la imprimo por pantalla en un foreach.

```
package patofer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static <T> void main(String[] args)  {

        List<Pais> listPais = new ArrayList<>();
        
        listPais.add(new Pais(1, "Chile"));
        listPais.add(new Pais(2, "Usa"));
        listPais.add(new Pais(3, "Mexico"));
        
        for (Pais pais : listPais) {
            System.out.println(pais);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Salida por consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

saludos espero que haber ayudado.

Comment: muchas gracias pero no es eso lo que necesito, yo tengo un webservice con consultas de entitymanager sobre el archivo paises.odb, que me devuelven un objeto tipo lista

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias pero no es eso lo que necesito, yo tengo un webservice con consultas de entitymanager sobre el archivo paises.odb, que me devuelven un objeto tipo lista

TypedQuery consulta = (TypedQuery) entityManager.createQuery("SELECT pais FROM Pais pais WHERE pais.codigoDivisa = '" + codigoDivisa + "'");

```
    List<Pais> paises = consulta.getResultList();

    entityManager.close();
    entityManagerFactory.close();

    return paises;
```

luego desde cliente, hago la peticion a esa consulta devolviendome ese return paises, de la forma que yo lo tengo, coloco ese return en una lista y luego la imprimo pero me devuelve 
servidorwebservices.Pais@43556938

por lo que necesito es encontrar el modo de que ese servidorwebservices.Pais@43556938 sea el texto del return del servidor